# I need to turn my phone off through a computer. Help, please!

Tags: remote-control, remote-access

I need to turn my mobile device off through my PC and currently I can't access my mobile phone. My sensor was bugged, and any calls made via messenger, viber or whatsapp would mean my mobile's device turning black. If I could restart my device, or even just turn it off, the problem wouldn't persist. Please help!

Comment: Do the volume and power buttons still work?

Comment: @HEWhoDoesn'tKnow Yes, the power button and my volume button works, but unfortunately my phone can't be restarted just with those. Or can it? I really need to turn my phone off, help!!

Comment: It could, on some phones. What kind of phone do you have?

Comment: @HEWhoDoesn'tKnow Well, I have a "Oppo F3" and even when it was working, pressing my "Power Off" button would just display a "Swipe to power off" fucntion. Long pressing the power button would not result into anything specific, as it does in so many other devices. Virtually, there was no way I could restart my phone, cuase as it seems, there just isn't a restart function in my phone! I've tried many stuffs, but will I be able to power off my device? Help!!

Comment: Posted an answer @Craman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Force restart your phone

> Firstly, unplug the charger if your phone is connected to a charger.
>
> **Press and hold both the Power and Volume Up buttons for at least 8 seconds, until the phone is turned on.**

- Remove the phone case if there is one to avoid phone buttons being stuck.
- If you cannot force restart your phone, plug in your phone with the original charger and let it charge for up to 30 minutes, then try again.
- Pictures, settings and paths might differ from those of your phone, but that do not affect the description in this article.

[Reference Link](https://oppo-in.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1251/kw/force%20restart)